# Hibernate аннотации(каскадное удаление)

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Есть 3 класса.
**Класс Гость**

```
@Proxy(lazy = false)
@Entity
@Table(name = "guest")
public class Guest extends HotelEntity {
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;

    @OneToMany( cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<GuestRoomInfo> guestRoomInfoList ;

    @OneToMany( cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<GuestServiceInfo> guestServiceInfoList ;


    public Guest( String name, String surName) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surName;
    }

       public Guest(){}

GETTERS,SETTERS
}
```

**Класс Комната**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "room")
public class Room extends HotelEntity implements Serializable{
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "number")
    private Integer number;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "cost")
    private Integer cost;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "capacity")
    private Integer capacity;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "stars")
    private Integer stars;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private RoomStatus status;


    public Room (Integer number,  Integer cost, Integer capacity, Integer stars) {
        this.number = number;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.stars = stars;
        this.status=RoomStatus.FREE;
    }

    public Room(){}

    getters,setters...
}
```

**И класс, где хранится инфа о госте и комнате**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "guestroominfo")
public class GuestRoomInfo extends HotelEntity {

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="guest")
    private Guest guest;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="room")
    private Room room;

    public GuestRoomInfo(Guest guest, Room room, Date arrivaldate, Date departuredate, Boolean isStillLiving) {
        this.guest=guest;
        this.room=room;
    }

    public GuestRoomInfo(){}

    getters,setters...
}
```

Лишние методы выкинул для простоты. Не получается каскадное удаление. По идее< при удалении гостя должна удаляться и guestroominfo.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`hotel7`.`guestroominfo`, CONSTRAINT `FK1AD7D5E128946912` FOREIGN KEY (`guest`) REFERENCES `guest` (`id`))
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` к аннотации `@OneToOne` в классе `guestroominfo`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "guestroominfo")
public class GuestRoomInfo extends HotelEntity {

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "guest")
    private Guest guest;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "room")
    private Room room;

    public GuestRoomInfo(Guest guest, Room room, Date arrivaldate, Date
            departuredate, Boolean isStillLiving) {
        this.guest = guest;
        this.room = room;
    }
}
```

и еще нужно добавить аннотацию `@Cascade` в классе `guest`:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@Cascade(CascadeType.DELETE)
private List<GuestRoomInfo> guestRoomInfoList;
```

Comment: Я хочу, чтобы при удалении гостя удалялось guestroominfo. В классе гость у меня есть такая аннотация. Выдает указанную выше ошибку.

Comment: добавил, но ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Почему-то idea не может импортировать класс для  @Cascade(CascadeType.DELETE)   DELETE подчеркивает красным. Это библиотеки нету какой-то? У меня hibernate 4

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71531/discussion-between-andreyatake-and-drakonoved).